# How do I let Visual studio know about web root different from wwwroot?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio shows nice icon and customised context menu for `wwwroot` directory as a web root.

I am curious, is there any option to let VS know that another directory was designed as a web root with `UseWebRoot` method and treat it appropriately instead of just showing it as a regular folder?

[image]

Comment: Not in that way. You can configure the static files middleware to use a different directory, but the UI niceties in VS only applies to wwwroot.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Sad to hear =‘(

Comment: That said, I wouldn't rule out the possibility of some extension that would allow you to do something with that. I don't know of anything myself, but might be worth spending a little time browsing the Visual Studio extensions marketplace to see if there's something for you.